# Can't query BigQuery table that was loaded from a Google Sheet because of data type

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I created the table successfully from the Google Sheet. Then I tried to query it which gives the following error:

```
Could not convert value to integer
```

I tried to use cast to convert it to string but I kept getting that error. This is my query:

```
SELECT
 Store, 
CAST ( Timestamp AS DATE) AS TS, 
Agent_Name, 
Product_Category, 
CAST ( What_was_the_QMan_ticket_number_for_this_client_ AS STRING) AS QmanT, 
Freeme, 
LTE 
FROM `tester-253410.test1.Ballito` 
ORDER BY TS DESC
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by table you mean [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources), you can create external table by explicitly specifying table schema (with column types) in [bq mk](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#creating_a_table_definition_using_an_inline_schema

Column 'What_was_the_QMan_ticket_number_for_this_client_' can be specified as string during table creation.